# AASM: Call event for multiple records(array) at once

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have AASM event which changes status of the record.

```
    event :change_status do
      transitions from: [:created], to: :confirmed
    end
```

Currently in the code I'm going through each passed record and call an event, like:

```
  def status_update(ids)
    payments = Payment.where(id: ids)
    payments.each do |payment|
      if payment.valid?
        payment.change_status
        payment.save
      end
    end
  end
```

Is it somehow possible to call `change_status` for all records at once (in bulk), not just go through each record? Otherwise it's time consuming, especially if there are a lot of records.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. 
Since the record is already saved, try skipping the `valid?` method and also call the bang(!) method like this `Payment.where(id: ids).map(&:change_status!)`. If there are no callbacks you can try to update the column directly using `Payment.where(id: ids).update_all(status: "confirmed")`

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Validation is indeed needed, as there are some date and plenty others which should be checked, there is a reason for that :)

Comment: Then that kind of answers your own questions. If you want to call the validations on all the records you have to iterate through them. Use `.find_each` and do it in batches unless you know that the list of ids is reasonably short.

Comment: Thanks! @max `.find_each`, already uses batches, so it's a good option. The question, then how to call `.valid?` in `.find_each`? I think it's not possible, because as we mentioned => need to go through each record.

Comment: Its exactlly the same as if you called `.each`. It loads a batch and then yields each record to the block. There really is no way around this if you want to use validations and callbacks so I would stop procastinating if those are your requirements.